# Trouble modifying data within struct

Tags: c++

I'm trying to modify data within a struct and cant seem to get it working.
    Happy to provide more information if necessary.

actTree returns a binary search tree.

findNode returns a node on that tree.

Data() returns actData.

````
```
struct actData
{

    string year,award,winner,name,film;

};

```
void modifyActRecord() {
        cout << "Enter the name of the film for the movie data you would like to modify:" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        cout << "Which field would you like to modify?" << endl;
        cout << "Your choices are year, award, winner, name, film" 
        << endl;
    string f;
    getline(cin, f);
    if (f == "year") {
        cout << "What would you like to change it to?" << endl;
        string in;
        getline(cin, in);

        //line in question
        actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year = in;
}
````

```
I can access the code fine with:
cout << actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year;

but cannot modify it with:
actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year = in;
```

Comment: The `data().year` is something that is not an lvalue (that which cannot be assigned to).

Comment: It seems that you're trying to modify rvalue. `Data()` should return `actData&`.

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, it's dangerous to `ignore` before an IO operation. Sooner or later you'll find yourself discarding data you wanted because there was noting in the stream that needed discarding. If you have to ignore something, it's better to place the `ignore` after the operation that leaves the data in the stream.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], presumably as others have stated `Data()` doens't return a reference

Answer (score 1):

Only lvalues can be assigned a value to. This means that only lvalues are allowed to be on the left side of an expression. You must know where an object is, before you can modify it. lvalue can be thought of as the address itself, though this might cause confusion between lvalue and pointers.

```
int x;               // x is an lvalue
int* p;              // *p is an lvalue
int a[100];          // a[42] is an lvalue; equivalent to *(a+42)
                     // note: a itself is also an lvalue
struct S { int m; };
struct S s;          // s and s.m are lvalues
struct S* p2 = &s;   // p2->m is an lvalue; equivalent to (*p2).m
                     // note: p2 and *p2 are also lvalues
```

rvalue on the other hand is the value of an expression. In the above code, think of `x` as the lvalue, and the `value of x` as the rvalue. Think of `*p` as an lvalue, and the `value of *p` as an rvalue. And so on

```
int x, y;
int z = 2*x + 3*y;
```

In the above example, `x`,`y` and `z` are lvalues. The expressions on the other hand : `2*x`, `3*y`, even `(2*x + 3*y)` are all rvalues. Since an rvalue is just a value, and not the location of a value, it can't be assigned to, just like you cannot say 2*x = 4, because it is simply incorrect.

So, in your example, `data().year` is not an lvalue. So it cannot be assigned to, only used. That is the reason, `cout << actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year;` works fine, but `actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year = in;` does not, since you are probably returning `actData`. You need to return a modifiable lvalue, which would be `actData&` in your case.

```
class Node
{
    actData m_data;
    public:
        actData Data()
        {
            return m_data;//returning value of m_data, not the address
        }
        /*Change above function to below function*/
        actData* Data()
        {
            return &m_data;//returning address here so that it can be modified
        }
};
```

Doing the above should make `actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year = in;` work.

Comment: For someone who doesn't know what an lvalue is, this answer is really hard to understand. It would be better to present one example at a time an explain why it can be assigned to or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer provided by @Mohitesh Kumar is right, nut I do not know much about `lvalue` and `rvalue`.

What I do know, is that `actTree->findNode(s)->Data()` returns an object, and 
`actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year` is a member of that object.
so when you write `actTree->findNode(s)->Data().year = in;`, you are assigning a value to the member of the returned object, but not modifying `actTree`.

Something you could have done is:

```
someObject = actTree->findNode(s)->Data();
someObject.year = in;
```

even so, it does not modify `actTree`. Then may be you should create a setter method for `data` and pass in the value of `someObject`